# Pinterest style image sharing for Facebook & Twitter

Tags: facebook, image, twitter, share

We have several pages that contain multiple images we would like to make "Social". I've successfully embedded the code for the Pinterest "Pin It" widget for each of theses images. After an extensive search I have not found a solution to "Share" or "Tweet" these images in a similar manor.

I am aware of the meta tags that Facebook uses and the Twitter Cards used by Twitter. However this tags are page specific, not image specific. And I don't want to rely on the user to flip through thumbnails to select the image intended to be shared.

So... does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not use multiple share buttons, each of them with an absolute URL to the image? Like so for Facebook...

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=[App ID]";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://[full-path-to-image].jpg" data-type="button_count"></div>
```

And like so for Twitter...

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://[full-path-to-image].jpg" data-via="{Twitter handle}">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

You'll need to replace some variables in the above code, and generate a Facebook App ID, by visiting http://developer.facebook.com

You only need to include the script elements once. Then duplicate the `<div>`/`<a href>` for each image.

Comment: Not sure about the Facebook code, but looks to me like the twitter one would post as if coming from our own account. Am I mistaken?

Comment: The data-via variable will append 'via @username' at the end of the tweet. So it won't come from your account, but will display a link back to your account. If you don't want this, you can remove data-via from the href

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your solutions works so I'm marking as answered. But I did want to comment that due to the limitations of the Facebook and Twitter widgets, this isn't quite as nice as the Pinterest "Pin It" widget. Setting the data-href value to be the image url does display the image, but you cannot set a default text and the link back is only to the image, not the page the image is located. Twitter allows for this, but doesn't display the image (Have to use Twitter Cards for that).